# Multiple loops importing and exporting from functions

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, I've only had about a year of on and off tinkering with it, and I've been stumped my my latest idea, I enjoy making simple stupid games and I think I've gone a little out of reach with this one, basically it's a cookie clicker style game where I have one function that I'm trying to make import the total amount from the script and then go into a loop where it takes the amount adds one times how many vats you have (bvats and bvatl are just so that I can make a shop later and change the variables to make it produce const more efficiently) and then export that value to the script and sleep for a bit before looping. The second function is where you do actions like listing commands or where you will (eventually) go to the shop, it is constantly prompted and it is also where you see the total amount of coast you have, my problem is the loop stops generating (or the second function stops displaying) the constantly gaining amount of coast after one, so if anyone is willing to help it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
# coding: utf-8
# coding: utf-8
#Imports and vaules:
import time
import threading 
import thread
from threading import Thread
game = "game"
over = "over"
#const is money
Const = 0 
#vat stuff
bvats = 1
bvatl = 4
#Game start
def Vats():
    global bvatl
    global bvats
    global Const
    while bvats >= 1:
        Const = Const + 1 * int(bvats)
        return Const
        time.sleep(int(bvatl))

def Action():
    while game != over:
        action = raw_input("Yes Boss? Did you need something? ")
        if action == "List":
            print "List: Displays this message, try it in the shop it will list the items available"            
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "Shop: Goes to the shop"
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "Const: Displays how much Const™ you have in the bank"
            time.sleep(0.5)
        elif action == "Const":
            print "You have " + str(Const) + " Const™ in the bank" 

t1 = Thread(target = Vats())
t2 = Thread(target = Action())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Action()` method is not getting the `Const` value from the `Vats()` method. One way may be to use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) to pass the `Const` value between the two methods. I took this idea from [Python Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch12.html), under the section **Communicating Between Threads** (Note: I added a few extra lines so "Ctrl-C" can exit the program when I tested it) :

```
# coding: utf-8
# coding: utf-8
#Imports and vaules:
import time
import threading 
import thread
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
game = "game"
over = "over"
#const is money
Const = 0 
#vat stuff
bvats = 1
bvatl = 4
#Game start
def Vats(out_q):
    global bvatl
    global bvats
    global Const
    while bvats >= 1:
        Const = Const + 1 * int(bvats)
        #return Const
        time.sleep(int(bvatl))
        out_q.put(Const)

def Action(in_q):
    while game != over:
        Const = in_q.get()
        action = raw_input("Yes Boss? Did you need something? ")
        if action == "List":
            print "List: Displays this message, try it in the shop it will list the items available"            
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "Shop: Goes to the shop"
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "Const: Displays how much Const™ you have in the bank"
            time.sleep(0.5)
        elif action == "Const":
            print "You have " + str(Const) + " Const™ in the bank" 

q = Queue()
t1 = Thread(target = Vats, args=(q,))
t2 = Thread(target = Action, args=(q,))
t1.setDaemon(True)
t2.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
t2.start()
while True:
    pass
```